# Is there a utility function in Joomla 1.5 for rendering HTML tables? if so, please share

Tags: html, function, joomla, html-table

I am new to Joomla, so I was wondering if there is a function wherein I pass an array of headers and a two dimensional array for data (cells) and get the html markup required to display the same as a HTML table.

I am assuming since this approach works with Javascript frameworks, it should be available in Joomla too.

Answer (score 0):

If something like that exists, I would expect it to be in the JHTML class, but I'm not seeing anything.  Perhaps you can look through the API and find something to help:
[JHTML class](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/HTML/JHTML.html)

If you don't find anything, I think you could easily write up your own method.  Let me know if you need help doing so.